# Issue: Guest OS (Debian 3.0, 32-bit ) loads with read-only file system immediately upon booting in VMware Workstation 10 (Host OS: Windows 7, 32-bit)

Tags: virtualbox, debian, filesystems, vmware, read-only

Issue Summary:
A guest 32-bit Debian 3.0 virtual machine is opened using VMware. The guest OS loads a read-only file system on startup. Despite root access no file changes can be made to the virtual machine.

Guest OS Details:
Linux Kernel: 2.6.26 nonpreempt
Debian Version: 3.0 
OS Type: 32-bit (i686)
gcc version: 3.3.5
Guest OS provided as series of files: (.vmdk) (.vmsd) (.vmx) (.vmxf). These files were known to successfully open using some type of VMware software in the past (with write access).

Host OS #1 Details:
OS: Windows 7, 32-bit
VMware Workstation: 10.0.6
VMware Player: 6.0.6
BIOS Intel Virtualization Technology: ENABLED
BIOS Intel VT for Direct I/O: ENABLED
BIOS Intel Trusted Execution Technology: ENABLED

Host OS #2 Details: 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, 64-bit
VMware Workstation: 11.1.2
VMware Player: 7.1.2

Prompt #1 (Always appears on host OS when first running the virtual machine file)
This virtual machine might have been moved or copied.
In order to configure certain management and networking features, VMware Workstation needs to know if this virtual machine was moved or copied. 
If you don't know, answer "I copied it".

Prompt #2 (During startup prior to login)
An early message appears something to the effect of “changing file system to read-only” then a number of subsequent messages appear such as: e.g. “syslogdchmod: changing permissions  of '/dev/xconsole/'”. Finally after logging in as root, attempting to create a file: sudo touch example.txt, gives: "touch: creating `example.txt’: Read-only file system."

Things I have tried:

1)  Various Virtual Machine Settings, such as: changing the guest OS type (Linux 2.6x Kernel, Debian 5, Other, Ubuntu, etc.)

2)  Selecting both “I moved it” and later “I copied it” on startup during Prompt #1.

3)  Using both VMware Workstation and VMware Player, on both the Windows 7,32-bit and Ubuntu 14.04.2

4)  Enabling and disabling all of the Virtualization Technology features in Windows BIOS (Host #1).

5)  Checking Virtualization is enabled (via command: sudo kvm-ok) on Ubuntu (Host #2)

6)  A similar issue appears to be the “path failover problem” as discussed here: http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-VMware-ESX-Linux-virtual-machines-and-read-only-file-systems. However in this case the file system becomes read only typically after some amount of time, rather than immediately upon startup. See http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=51306 for more details.

Questions:

It seems the latest VMware Player and Workstation do not support Debian 3.0. Is there any way to obtain legacy versions of this software that does? Could this problem be related to the fact that the virtual machine files were being recently configured and opened on another host OS? Any ideas on what else the problem could be?

Comment: Solution is to remount the file system with the command:
$ mount -o remount, rm /

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?  In 2 days you will be able to accept that as the answer, which will indicate that the problem is solved.  That's how we do it in Super User's Q&A format rather than adding "solved" to the title.  Thanks.

Comment: The forumism of editing titles to say "solved" stems from the fact that the forum format makes it difficult to mark a question as complete and it is not needed here. You can post an answer and then, in a couple of days, you should be able to use the "tick" that is next to your self answer in order to mark it as the correct answer and thus "solve" your question. We have a delay on marking self answers as correct to prevent abuse of the system and to give others a chance to post solutions but that should not stop you from posting a useful answer.